# Regex in search & replace: avoid fixed length of lookaround

Tags: regex, text-editor

In a long corpus of text, I want to make some corrections in certain
environments.  However, I am encountering problems when using regex with text
editors. I switched to **gedit** to have an editor which supports regex in
**search & replace**.

Crucially, I only want to make changes if the line starts with a certain
pattern (`\nm` or `\mb`).  The problem is that the element that I want to
replace (`o'` -> `o'o`) is not at a fixed length from the beginning of the line
and I can't include the regex in the lookbehind (the lookbehind fails).

Is there any way to include what I am looking for in a simple text editor
regex?  Or is this already a step where I have to learn how to script in, for
example, Python?

This is what the regex looks like so far.

```
(?<=\\(nm|mb)).*o'(?=(q|w|r|t|z|p|s|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|x|c|v|b|n|m|a|i|u|e))
```

Of course, I can't apply `.*` in the replace without losing its content.

Comment: It looks like you can replace `(q|w|r|t|z|p|s|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|x|c|v|b|n|m|a|i|u|e)` with the `[a-np-xz]` [character class](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#classes).

Comment: Is it a typo or you really don't want to match `o` and  `y`?

Comment: y i forgot, o I don't want to match :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a capture group around `.*` and a back-reference in the replacement.

Find: `(?<=\\(nm|mb))(.*)o'(?=(q|w|r|t|z|p|s|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|x|c|v|b|n|m|a|i|u|e))`

Replace: `\1o'o`

Comment: Hey Barmar,
I tried to use the back-reference in gedit and for whatever reason it did not work. However, it seemed rare to me, as the replace would just use "$1" as a string. Applying the capture group in Sublime (and replacing $1 with $2) however, everything worked out fine. Thank you! Today I learned about capture groups and back-references